# Bootstrap 4 responsible table with only vertical scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, responsive

I use Bootstrap 4 reponsible table.

I have a large table, with 8 colunms / 10 rows and would like to get a friendly display in 320 x 480 resolution for smartphones.

It is possible to turn off horizontal scrolling bar and arrange the table in order get columns being rows in small resolution sizes ?

Then only vertical scrolling would be needed, such like this very good made table :
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get similar type of tables using `jQuery Mobile's table reflow`.

Demo [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/table-reflow-stripes-strokes/).